# Passing array pointer to struct and acces the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I need to store a pointer to a char array in a struct, and then modify/access the arrays content. How can I do that?

I can only think of something similar to this, but I don't get to the complete compilable solution.

```
struct foo {
    unsigned char *array;
};
```

And then:

```
unsigned char array[512];
struct foo *foo;
foo->array = array;
```

In another function which receivers pointer to struct:

```
*(foo->array[0]) = 'K';
```

Comment: If you plan to store a null-zerminated string in the char array, use `char` instead of `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost fine:

```
foo->array[0] = 'K';
```

The problem with your code `*(foo->array[0])` is that you try to dereference a `char` which is not even a pointer.

You also need to allocate memory for the struct - currently `foo` points to some random memory location where an access will most likely crash your program:

```
struct foo *foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));
```

Comment: Aye, I knew that I was near to the solution. Thanks for your help!
I know about the malloc, I am using that but just left it blank for not overflooding my question. Thanks for the hint anyways!

Comment: shouldn't it be:  malloc(sizeof(foo));  ?

Comment: @Tectu: from `foo` being a pointer to `struct foo` the following the following assumptions are valid: the type of `*foo` is `struct foo` and thus `sizeof(*foo) == sizeof(struct foo)`. Using `*var` avoids having to write the name of the struct again.